# import xml respons google sheet

Tags: xml, google-sheets

I am trying to use the `IMPORTXML` function in Google Spreadsheet to get the value 44 from a page with as source as shown below (*please do not enter source code as pictures*) into the sheet. I seem to keep messing up the XPath syntax. My current function call looks like this:

```
*... please enter*
```

[image]

Comment: please add the code not image of code

Answer (score 0):

You probably get what you want like this:

```
IMPORTXML("https://xy.com/foobar", "//collective2/positionstatus/position/text()")
```